# How to update redux slice?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I have a problem, I can't update the user's gold with this code.
I'd like to update the user's gold from his current gold to current gold + 100 every 10 seconds.

This code doesn't work, I think I misunderstood something but can't figure out what!
I'd like the gold to be dispatched when I leave the page. I mean I have my current gold shown in the header for example and in the page I can see every 10 secs from 0 my gold updated ... once I leave the page in the header I'd like to have my current gold + the gold earn.

`useEffect` in my component:

```
const [chrono, setChrono] = useState<number>(0);
const user: any = useSelector((state: any) => state.user);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [gold, setGold] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  const updateGold = setInterval(() => {
    setGold((gold) => gold + 100);
  }, 10000);

  return () => {
    dispatch(
      userSlice.actions.update({
        ...user,
        gold: user.gold + gold,
      })
    );
    clearInterval(updateGold);
  };
}, []);
```

reducer

```
update: (state: any, { payload }) => {
  console.log("action =>", payload);
  return {
    ...state,
    ...payload,
  };
},
```

Comment: You should be able to update *just* the `gold` property in state without needing to shallow copy the `user` object from state back into the action. What exactly isn't working though?

Comment: Gold in redux stays at the the default value, there is nothing updated

Comment: Also, why *not* just update the `user.gold` state directly every 10s instead of updating local state and then trying to synchronize it later?

Comment: How can I do that ? Im pretty new at redux im doing som exercices x)

Comment: It would be so good if I could update just gold from the use effect.
but im not really good up date object in the reducer at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it makes more sense and would be simpler to dispatch the an update action on the interval instead of updating local state and synchronizing state later.

Example:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  const updateGold = setInterval(() => {
    dispatch(
      userSlice.actions.addGold(100);
    );
  }, 10000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(updateGold);
  };
}, []);
```

Slice

```
addGold: (state: any, { payload }) => {
  state.gold = state.gold + payload;
},
```